# Prevent child component <style> added with innerHtml to be applied to parent

Tags: angular, innerhtml

How do i prevent child component style, added to child with innerHtml, to be applied to parent? Coincidentally, the parent could already have a css class with same name. If ViewEncapsulation is set to Native, this seems to work properly (child has red background, parent has green), but with Emulated it doesn't. I can't use Native, as it is said, it's not supported by all browsers.

app.ts

```
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule, DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import {Component, Input, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<div class="header">
    <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
</div>
<hr>
  <child [content]="content"></child>
`,

})

export class App {
  name:string;
  content:string = '<style>.header {background-color:red;color:white;}</style><div class="header">This is child content</div>'
  constructor(public ds: DomSanitizer) {
    this.content = this.ds.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.content);
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template:`<div [innerHtml]="content"></div>`,
  encapsulation:ViewEncapsulation.Emulated
//  encapsulation:ViewEncapsulation.Native
})
export class child{
 @Input('content') content;

}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App, child ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

style.css

```
.header {
      background-color:green;
      color:white;
}
```

[Plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/8m9TZoFf49aHtXTWKu84?p=preview)

Comment: native mode doesn't work in Firefox, it does work in Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My findings: (Angular 5) Emulate encapsulation doesn't work, because it is applied at compile time only, Native is applied at runtime, but it can't be used, because it's not supported across browsers. Since angular does not control innerHtml at runtime, html is inserted directly into the dom and this can cause classes with existing names, to get unintentionally overridden by inserted html/css.
So currently, the only solution to avoid this problem, is to manually rename css classes and their references in html, before inserting it to the dom. That's what angular does to isolate css, when :host is specified in styles decorator. There is also currently no way to trigger angular's compilation of custom css/html string at runtime that would do renaming for us, although functionallity obviously exists.

Answer (score 0):

Any component should really have it's own stylesheet. There you could add something like this:

```
:host {
  //styling
}
:host > div { //etc }
```

Anything with :host applies to that component. Would this not fix your issue?

If for example you knew what structure you would be adding, you could write it into the component decorator:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: `<div [innerHtml]="content"></div>`,
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated,
  styles: [ ':host { position: absolute; top: 10%; }' ]
})
```

Then you could still add your innerHtml and the styling would apply to it. So in the above case, the :host {} styling should apply to the  component when it is deployed in the DOM. From that point on, if you know what structure/tags/classes your innerHtml will contain, it's just a matter of styling for them.

Or. Instead of styles like above, change it to it's own stylesheet:

```
  styleUrls: ['/some/path/to/stylesheet.css']
```

Comment: child component gets it's style from string, not from styles metatag. Please explain how injected style could be applied to child only. This example is minified only for demonstration

Comment: Could you not give it it's own stylesheet? It does address your issue after all.

Comment: i don't understand what you mean, like i should give it it's own stylesheet? If yes, how do i make angular render and apply it to child innerHtml?

Comment: Updated the answer, given styles and styleUrls as examples.

Comment: i don't know what css or html will be added to innerHtml of the child, it just needs to be isolated from parent. Can :host somehow be added to unknown css and compiled by angular? Can't use styleurls as css and html is received in a string

Comment: Well anything as :host * { } from that point on should only apply to that component. So since you can't have it as a separate file you'll have to use the styles: [] methodology. Ofc, not knowing the html is going to be tricky for you ...

Comment: i can separate style and html in two different strings. Can i then dynamically apply  my css string to styles [] ? Is it possible this is an angular bug, because it works properly in Native encapsulation?